# What is the reason for my text go under footer?

Tags: html, css

I have this site

[link](http://reliancetrustgroup.com/news/)

As you can see in the picture below ... go under footer text and not seen.
I tried to inspect the code to figure out where the problem but unfortunately I have not found ...

You can help me solve this problem please?

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't see the problem in Opera, Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: are you sure?not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure this is not a css problem.
The reason I think this is the case is because some times the page loads and the page behaves fine. This inconsistent behavior can be caused because your javascript is not being told to execute only after all the DOM elements are being created.

make sure your javascript is being called in the footer of your site, or use `document.ready(function(){});` to make sure your javascript is being executed after all the elements it is changing load. Otherwise the javascript will not find the right handles since they do not exist yet.

Check this resource for how to properly use javascript:

https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/